# Why dispalying Primefaces Text editor code is not formatted

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsf, primefaces

I use **Primefaces** Text editor to allow the creation of content in a Forum application developed with **JSF**. If the user introduces code in the [Text editor](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml?jfwid=bbd6e), it is displayed correctly in the [Text editor](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml?jfwid=bbd6e) but when displaying the content with **<h:outputText value="#{post.content}" escape="false"/>**, the part that contains the code is displayed as plain text and not as code.

[Primefaces Text editor code not formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCXaZ.png)

The code generated from Text editor is:

```
<pre class="ql-syntax" spellcheck="false"><video>
     <source src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4;  />
<video>
</pre>
```

After investigation, it appears that the "**ql-syntax**" style of the code part in Text Editor is not applied.

How can i display the code part introduced in the Text editor as being formatted code ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please provide a reproducer using https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: In the picture the video closing-tag is no closing-tag, so it seems it's not valid html

Comment: @Jasper de Vries: The goal is to display the code as being formatted as it is done at Stackverflow or other forums and not to correct the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for those facing the same problem.
It is necessary to put the **outputText** in divs of the following format to be able to apply the style of Text editor outside [Text editor](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml?jfwid=32285) itself .

```
<div class="ql-container ql-snow">                                                    
   <div class="ql-editor">
        <h:outputText value="#{post.content}"  escape="false"/>                                                          
   </div>                                                    
</div>
```